# Convert UTF-8 to Window 874 using PHP

Tags: php

I have encoded string like `ªÙªÑÂ  à¾ç§Íé¹`

Please check below function that i have used for decode(utf-8 to tis620) it.

```
function utf8_to_tis620($string) {
   $str = $string;
   $res = "";
   for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
      if (ord($str[$i]) == 224) {
        $unicode = ord($str[$i+2]) & 0x3F;
        $unicode |= (ord($str[$i+1]) & 0x3F) << 6;
        $unicode |= (ord($str[$i]) & 0x0F) << 12;
        $res .= chr($unicode-0x0E00+0xA0);
        $i += 2;
      } else {
        $res .= $str[$i];
      }
   }
   return $res;
}
```

So it will return string like `ชูชัย  Gงอ้น` but it isn't correct in THAI language.

Actually it should return `ชูชัย เพ็งอ้น` that is returned from http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx.

But there is used windows 874 decoding.

Please let me know how can i decode utf-8 to windows 874 in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to change the character encoding:

```
function utf8_to_tis620($string) {
    return mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'TIS-620');
}
```

As noted by [krasipenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5102590/krasipenkov) in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101988/convert-utf-8-to-window-874-using-php/40102393#comment67476658_40102393),

> There is small difference between ISO-8859-11 and TIS-620. ISO-8859-11 is
>   nearly identical to the national Thai standard TIS-620 (1990). The
>   sole difference is that ISO/IEC 8859-11 allocates non-breaking space
>   to code 0xA0, while TIS-620 leaves it undefined. (In practice, this
>   small distinction is usually ignored.)

Instead of `'TIS-620'`, you can use `'ISO-8859-11'` for the Windows 874 character encoding if needed.

Comment: Just got in mind that there is small difference between ISO-8859-11 and TIS-620

_"It is nearly identical to the national Thai standard TIS-620 (1990). The sole difference is that ISO/IEC 8859-11 allocates non-breaking space to code 0xA0, while TIS-620 leaves it undefined. (In practice, this small distinction is usually ignored.)"_

Comment: Hi dear, i have used your function like : function function_demo($input) {
   return @mb_convert_encoding($input, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-11');
}
echo function_demo("ªÙªÑÂ  à¾ç§Íé¹");

Comment: But still it isn't working for me it return "รยชรยรยชรย‘รย รย รยพรยงรยงรยรยฉรยน" but my correct string is "ชูชัย เพ็งอ้น"

Comment: Ohkay i have find this one from using another way.

Comment: You are correct in your way. my encoded string was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) for convert string to request character encoding.

```
$string= iconv('TIS-620','UTF-8//ignore',$string);
```